# How to change angular material input background

Tags: angular

Hello i am trying to change the background color of my angular material input just like https://portal.dojrp.com/login it is using the standard appearance of the angular material input theming but that has been removed from angular what should i do?

I have tried to use the following code but it has not done anything.

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex{

    background: none !important;
    
    }
```

Comment: Angular Material component coloring should be done via themes, not by css. The way of styling components via the global styles is very error prone since you glue yourself to a libraries css class names and dom structure which can change at any time. I had this happen in a project where some styles were broken after an angular material update. Trust me, you do not want that. Check https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: The above is true. But have you tried `::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your component css file as well as style.scss file to change the background of the mat-input

**your component.ts**

```
   ::ng-deep .mat-input-element {
     background: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
   }
```

or

```
 .mat-input-element {
     background: rgb(76, 0, 255) !important;
  }
```

or

```
  ::ng-deep 
    .mat-form-field .mat-form-field-flex{
      background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); 
   }
```

as well as you can use your style.scss file. This will affect all the mat-input in your project.

```
.mat-input-element {
    background: rgb(181, 255, 10) !important;
 }
```

or

```
.mat-form-field .mat-form-field-flex{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 119);
  }
```

[check app.component.ts and style.scss](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-new-pwdwn7?file=src/styles.css)